# MappingEntityClassesException - Mapping definition neither have entities nor collection

Tags: shopware

I have written a product import which imports some product data via CLI command.
When i run it multiple times the defined product property (`color`) does not get overwritten but adden.

**Example**

- First run - color: red
- Second run: - color: green

The importer sums the properties up, So the color has then multiple values - red AND green.
I want to solve this by deleting the product properties before the importer runs by this code:

```
$items = $this->productPropertyRepository->search((new Criteria())->addFilter(new EqualsAnyFilter('productId',
        $productIds)), Context::createDefaultContext());

$ids = [];
foreach ($items as $item) {
    $ids[] = ['productId' => $item['product_id'], 'productVersionId' => $item['product_version_id']];
}
if ($ids) {
    $this->productPropertyRepository->delete($ids, Context::createDefaultContext());
}
```

But this does not work because there is no `ProductPropertyEntity` class in Shopware 6.
I get an exception when execution the first line.

> [Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\Exception\MappingEntityClassesException]
> Mapping definition neither have entities nor collection.

Whats the best way to avoid keeping orphaned data in this case?